# Remote Oracle connection with delphi

Tags: sql, oracle, delphi, oracle11g

Remote Oracle connection with Delphi

Connect is true; but then

```
Error "ORA-12545 connect field because target host or object does not exist"
```

ADO connection string

```
"Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Data Source=10.45.25.26:1521/ORCL;Database=ORCL;User Id=system;password:=123"
```

Client computer ODAC 11g 32bit installed.

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: [Look here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-12545)

Comment: Either the connect string is wrong, or the Listener for the database is not running.

Comment: Can you connect successfully to the same database with SQL Plus?

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect successfully to the same database with Oracle SQL Developer?
Without access to the oracle client Oracle SQL Developer.
Oracle SQL Developer 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the "/ORCL" is used for the Data Source property in the connection string.  This property should be either IP:PORT or FQDN (Fully qualified domain name).

> Data Source=10.45.25.26:1521/ORCL

Change to:

> Data Source=10.45.25.26:1521

Also, the password property should use "=" not ":="

> password=123